# Wix Custom Action only on uninstall

Tags: wix

I am having a problem getting a Custom action to only run when I am uninstalling my service using Wix.

```xml
<CustomAction Id='InstallService'
              FileKey='Service.exe'
              ExeCommand='install'
              Execute='immediate'
              Return='check'
              Impersonate='yes'>NOT Installed</CustomAction>

<CustomAction Id='UninstallService'
              FileKey='Service.exe'
              ExeCommand='uninstall'
              Execute='immediate'
              Return='check'
              Impersonate='yes'>Installed AND NOT REINSTALL</CustomAction>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='UninstallService' After='StopServices'/>
  <Custom Action='InstallService' Before='StartServices'/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

this is the component ...

```xml
  <Component Id="ProductComponent">
    <File Id="MyService.exe"
          Name="MyService.exe"
          Source="..\MyService\bin\Release\MyService.exe"
          Vital="yes"
          KeyPath="yes"
          DiskId="1"/>

    ...

    <ServiceControl Id='ServiceControl'
                    Name='MyService'
                    Start='install'
                    Stop='both'/>
  </Component>
```

When I run the installer I get an error. Looking in the event log I find this ...

Product: MyService -- Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: UninstallService, location: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyService\MyService.exe, command: uninstall

I have also tried this ...

```xml
<CustomAction Id='UninstallService'
              FileKey='Service.exe'
              ExeCommand='uninstall'
              Execute='immediate'
              Return='check'
              Impersonate='yes'>Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</CustomAction>
```

Note: I am using custom actions to install/uninstall the service because I've made use of [TopShelf.NET](http://topshelf-project.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to tie the action of the custom action to the action state of the Component.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="UninstallService">$ProductComponent=2</Custom>
   <Custom Action="InstallService">$ProductComponent=3</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Also, you're going to need your `CustomAction` elements to be `Execute='deferred'`.

Also, text in the `CustomAction` element is only allowed if you're creating a script custom action. It doesn't seem like that's what you are doing.

Adding custom actions requires quite a bit of understanding. It is unfortunate that a 3rd party platform would [force you to use custom actions](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/8/17/zataoca-custom-actions-are-generally-an-admission-of-failure).

Comment: brilliant, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I actually ended up using ?ProductComponent=3 for uninstall and $ProductComponent=3 for install and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Using ?ProductComponent=3 means that the uninstall will fire even if the Component is not being removed. For example, during repair, I expect your uninstall custom action will be called. Probably not the goal. :)

Comment: When I tried $ProductComponent=2 is didn't work. So I searched around and found the ? qualifier

Comment: I've changed it back to $ProductComponent=2 and it seems fine now. I'm not sure what was going on before, perhaps something out of step.

Comment: Where can I lookup these States? 2 = Uninstall, 3 = Install and 1 = Reinstall?